# Error inflating class fragment for maps, attaching my code

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

My layout for maps

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

My Maps java

```
package com.example.tracker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.*;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class Tracking extends FragmentActivity  {

    private GoogleMap map;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tracking);
 }
}
```

My Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tracker" android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk 
        android:minSdkVersion="8" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.tracker.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-feature 
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use Google Maps Android 
        API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application 
        android:allowBackup="true" 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity 
            android:name="com.example.tracker.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity 
            android:name="com.example.tracker.Inbus"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <activity 
            android:name="com.example.tracker.Inbay"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <activity 
            android:name="com.example.tracker.Tracking"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBI3uLoMVsz-wVfTo3jAQboMfPt6n_zH5M" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Finally the logcat error

```
04-01 10:22:01.269: I/Adreno200-EGL(5511): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_2.3.04.01.01.032.173 +  NOTHING
04-01 10:22:03.842: W/dalvikvm(5511): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40db9450)
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tracker/com.example.tracker.Tracking}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2062)
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2087)
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133)
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1198)
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4803)
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:258)
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511):     at com.example.tracker.Tracking.onCreate(Tracking.java:11)
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2026)
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511):     ... 11 more
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:584)
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:552)
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4656)
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511):     ... 20 more
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:574)
04-01 10:22:03.862: E/AndroidRuntime(5511):     ... 23 more
```

---

Comment: have you referenced google play services in your android project? Do you use `MapFragment` anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Its seems like you not add google-play-service library properly. 
You have to import google-play-service library project from your sdk path.
and use this library in your project.

For step by step guidelines, refer this post [Google Map v2](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Answer (score 0):

you need to download Google Play Services from the Android SDK Manager is under Extras if you are using eclipse you need to import the project and added as dependence of your the project is [sdk_folder]/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib and you are done.

Here is the official documentation 
please visit: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html